# Laravel Method Model Binding?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm moving a large project from CodeIgniter to Laravel 5, and am encountering a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I know you can do route model binding, and I've been using it extensively without problem, and I know you can do method injection, such as injecting the Request into the method.

But my "problem" is I have multiple classes with the same name, but for different sections of the project, for example:

```
App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article
App\Models\News\Article
App\Models\Minisite\Resources\Article
```

As you can see, I have 3 different `Article` models. One for Knowledgebase Articles, one for news articles and one for departmental resource articles.

However, with route model binding, it seems I can only bind one model to a keyword, and since my URLs each have the keyword Article, it doesn't really work.

So my question is, is it possible to inject the related model into the method by specifying it as a parameter? Or do I need to hard code it into the method by saying:

```
$article = App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article::find($some_id);
```

Or can I do something like this:

```
public function show(App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article $article)
{
   // code
}
```

At the moment, if I try to inject the article, `$article` becomes a new instance of the Article model, rather than the model record. It just seems a bit weird that the framework would make you manually retrieve the model for each method.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, with route model binding, it seems I can only bind one model to a keyword, and since my URLs each have the keyword Article, it doesn't really work.

You can use a different keyword in the bindings for each type.

```
// in the router
$router->model('kbarticle', 'App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article');
$router->model('newsarticle', 'App\Models\News\Article');
$router->model('sitearticle', 'App\Models\Minisite\Resources\Article');

// in your routes file
Route::get('knowledge/{kbarticle}', function(App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article $article) {});
Route::get('news/{newsarticle}', function(App\Models\News\Article $article) {});
Route::get('site/{sitearticle}', function(App\Models\Minisite\Resources\Article $article) {});
```

Comment: Could I use this approach with `Route::resource()`? Either way, this is helpful as well

Comment: @PhilCross I don't use `Route::resource()` much, sorry. Maybe?

Comment: I decided to replace route resources with individual routes (get/post/put etc). At least this way I can control the names of the model alias' better in the Route file.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just import the class with and alias?

```
<?php
use App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article as MyArticle
```

Then on your function just do this:

```
public function show(MyArtcile $article)
{
   // code
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I was clear with what I needed! I can bind a model to a method, but just not populate it automatically from the route, without using a route model binding. I'll try update my question.

Comment: Could this be done in the `app/app.php` file under the `'aliases' => [ ... 'KBArticle' => 'App\Models\Knowledgebase\Article', ...]`? That would save time if it was a possibility.

Comment: Oh I get it, why don't you define your model on the constructor of the controller?

Comment: @TimLewis yes you can, you can add an alias for your users model for example , just try it adding this at the end of your app.php, `'Megauser' => 'App\User''` then on your controllers do `use Megauser;`